# Is it possible to escape the '%' symbol in text in LaTeX?

Tags: minted

```tex
\usepackage{drawstack}

\newcommand{\celladdr}[1]{
  \draw[<-,line width=0.7pt] (0,\value{cellnb}-0.5) +(2,\value{ptrnb}*0.1) -- +(2.5,\value{ptrnb}*0.45);
  \draw (2.5,\value{ptrnb}*0.5+\value{cellnb}) node[anchor=north west,yshift=-1.6ex] {\mintinline{py}{#1}};
}

\newcommand{\finishframev}[1]{
  \draw[snake=brace, line width=0.6pt, segment amplitude=7pt]
  (-2,\value{cellnb}-0.5) -- (-2,\value{startframe}-0.5);
  \node[label=left:\rotatebox{90}{#1}] at (-2.2cm,\value{cellnb}*0.5+\value{startframe}*0.5-0.5) {};
}
```

```
\item Stack Diagram: \\
\begin{drawstack}
%   Within the environment, draw stack elements with 
  \startframe
  \cell{RIP} \celladdr{0xff}
  \cell{SFP} \celladdr{ESP}
  \padding{1}{compiler padding}
  \cell{buf[8]} \celladdr{(\%ESP)-20} \cellcom{(This cell not to scale)}
  \finishframev{display}
\end{drawstack}
```

prints out:
[image]

And Overleaf wont compile if i don't include the backslash. How do I just get `%ESP`?

Comment: To get the best possible answer, please provide a complete compileable example.  However, one way would be to `\catcode\`\%=12 ` before the `drawstack` environment...you could restore it to a value of 14 afterward.  (of course, in such a case, no comments are allowed in the environment)

Comment: Without knowing how you've defined `\celladdr` there's not much we can tell you. That command is not part of the standard `drawstack` package and is not defined by anything else in the standard TeX distribution.

Comment: The output you show suggests that the command is reading its argument verbatim, but as you have not shown the definition of any commands in the fragment it is hard to guess how it might be defined or if it provides a built in way to access %

Comment: @DonHosek Sorry! I just added it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing those strings to `\mintinline` so the output is controlled by Pygments.

The simplest solution is to disable `%` as a comment character for the duration of the environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{drawstack}
\usepackage{minted}

\newcommand{\celladdr}[1]{%
  \draw[<-,line width=0.7pt]
    (0,\value{cellnb}-0.5)+(2,\value{ptrnb}*0.1) -- +(2.5,\value{ptrnb}*0.45);
  \draw (2.5,\value{ptrnb}*0.5+\value{cellnb}) 
    node[anchor=north west,yshift=-1.6ex] {\mintinline{py}{#1}};
}

\newcommand{\finishframev}[1]{%
  \draw[snake=brace, line width=0.6pt, segment amplitude=7pt]
    (-2,\value{cellnb}-0.5) -- (-2,\value{startframe}-0.5);
  \node[label=left:\rotatebox{90}{#1}]
    at (-2.2cm,\value{cellnb}*0.5+\value{startframe}*0.5-0.5) {};
}

\begin{document}
\begin{drawstack}\catcode`\%=12
  \startframe
  \cell{RIP} \celladdr{0xff}
  \cell{SFP} \celladdr{ESP}
  \padding{1}{compiler padding}
  \cell{buf[8]} \celladdr{(%ESP)-20} \cellcom{(This cell not to scale)}
  \finishframev{display}
\end{drawstack}

\end{document}
```

Of course you can't have comments in that environment.

[image]